# Naive Inheritance Problem - Java

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

G'day people,

I am feeling embarrass by asking such a naive question. But I can't understand one thing,
I have Inheritance structure like this,

[image]

B extends A, code I have wrote is as below,

**Class A**

```
public class A{
    private int pos = 0;
    public A(){
        this.pos = 12;
    }
    public int getPos(){
        return this.pos;
    }
}
```

**Class B**

```
public class B extends A{
    int spec = 15;
    public B(){
        super();
    }
    public int getSpec(){
        return this.spec;
    }
}
```

And I have one more class to test, Which will get us to my question.

**Class Test**

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        B a = new B();
        ArrayList<A> c = new ArrayList<A>();
        c.add(a);
        System.out.println(c.get(0).getPos());
        System.out.println(c.get(0).getSpec());
    }
}
```

Question : Now I am creating an instance of B, Which means I can access to my parent class's method `getPos()` and B's own method `getSpec()`. But if I create ArrayList with type A(...B is type A too, as it extends A...) and add my B's instance it losses it's ability to access it's own method. What am I doing wrong? Does ArrayList implementation is casting my B to A internally?

---

> Note : My basic understanding of inheritance is parent cannot access
>   child's method except they are protected. But Child can access their
>   parent class's method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the answers provided by [@Matt Ball](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369236/naive-inheritance-problem-java/7369252#7369252) and [@Hovercraft Full Of Eels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369236/naive-inheritance-problem-java/7369251#7369251), you can avoid having to ***explicitly cast*** by declaring methods implemented by the *subclass* as ***abstract*** methods in the *superclass*.

```
public abstract class A{
    .
    .
    public abstract int getSpec();
}
```

---

**EDIT-**

As mentioned by [@Kublai Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/697449/kublai-khan), it is necessary to then make the *superclass* an ***abstract*** class.

Comment: +1 and don't forget that `A` now needs to be an abstract class.

Answer (score 4):

There's no casting involved. What you're doing is no different from this:

```
A bAsA = new B():
```

While the object referred by bAsA is truly a B object, it is held by an A variable and thus only A methods are available (unless you explicitly cast it as a B variable).

Since your ArrayList is an ArrayList of A, each item in the ArrayList is treated as an A variable and only A methods are available.

Answer (score 4):

> Does ArrayList implementation is casting my B to A internally?

No. There is no "internal casting." **You,** the programmer, have told the compiler it's a list of `A`.

You have **declared** the `List` as `List<A>`, which you can read as *"a list of `A`"*. Since all `B` are `A`, you can add any `B` to a `List<A>`. On retrieval, however, you're only guaranteed to get back an `A`, not a `B` — because it's a `List<A>`, remember — so the compiler treats **everything** that comes out of the list as an `A`, even if (at runtime) it's an instance of `B`.

Comment: Thanks Matt, Now this makes sense :). Btw What if I want collection of child in one ArrayList? can I do something like ArrayList<Obejct>...; and then cast it each time? or is there any work around?

Comment: @Skeet: heavy casting gives a program a bad smell and suggests that one should look carefully at the program design because there's a good chance that it's broken and can be improved in a much more object-oriented fashion.

Comment: @Skeet I would not recommend casting. If you want to be able to call the same method on `A`s and `B` stop worrying about the type and just make `A` and `B` implement the same interface. Or, put a stub method in `A` that `B` can override.

Comment: @Skeet also it's generally good practice to declare `List<Foo>` or even looser constraints like `Collection<Foo>` or `Iterable<Foo>`. As I said in my previous comment: don't worry about an object's type. Start thinking in terms of what you can **do** with it.

Comment: +1 Thanks, Matt and Hovercraft, I will keep that in my mind, Nice answer